# How to set max width for a grid in a XAML view to the max dialog width?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, prism

I have a WPF project that is written using C# on the top of the [Prism framework](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism).

I have a button when pressed an I use `InteractionRequest` to show a dialog. The view of this dialog had a width of 550.

The view is designed with a Grid, I want the grid to have a width of 550 as well which is the max width of the dialog.

However, the grid seems to always stretch more than the dialog when the text in the column is long.

Here is a screenshot that would better explain the visual issue

[image]

The first line in the picture represents a `title` where the second line represents that `description`

Here is my XAML code that renders this dialog/view

```
<UserControl x:Class="Modules.Register.Views.RecallTransactionView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Modules.Register.Views"
             xmlns:fa="http://schemas.fontawesome.io/icons/"
             xmlns:materialDesign="http://materialdesigninxaml.net/winfx/xaml/themes"
             xmlns:prism="http://prismlibrary.com/"
             prism:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True"
             TextElement.Foreground="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignBody}"
             TextElement.FontWeight="Regular"
             TextElement.FontSize="14"
             TextOptions.TextFormattingMode="Ideal"
             TextOptions.TextRenderingMode="Auto"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             Width="550">

    <Grid Width="550" >

        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Dialog.SavedTransactions}"
                  AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                  IsReadOnly="True"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                  VerticalAlignment="Top"
                  CanUserAddRows="False"
                  VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
                  HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                  CellStyle="{StaticResource CenterDataGridCell}">

            <DataGrid.Columns>

                <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>

                <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Button VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                    Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}, 
                                                      Path=DataContext.SelectTransaction}"
                                    CommandParameter="{Binding}">

                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <fa:FontAwesome Icon="Eye"
                                                    FontSize="18" />

                                    <TextBlock Text="Recall"
                                               Padding="7 0 0 0" />
                                </StackPanel>
                            </Button>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>

            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>

    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

As you can see that both `Title` and `Description` have `TextWrapping="Wrap"` but for some reason it is not wrapping.

I am basicly trying to remove the horizontal scrollbar but forcing the text to wrap. How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to set the Width of first grid column to '*'

```
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="*">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```